# What happens with natural frequency on a rope which length is changing?

Tags: waves, acoustics, string, wavelength, stability

I was watching violin concerto, and I thought of two scenarios of sliding on the string and taking finger off the string as shown in the image:

[image: I. for sliding and II. for finger off]

Define $v = \sqrt{\frac{T}{\mu}} = f\lambda$, $T, \mu, v$ is (near) constant

For case I I figured to use $Asin(\frac{2n\pi}{L+dL}x-\omega (t+dt))$ which seems to fit boundary conditions just fine. But for case II although I did a little rubber band experiment that seems to prove that but I wonder how is that legitimate?

I came up with a guess that as the pulse travels down the rope at $v$, the same parts of the pulse will hit the boundary with a same period of $\frac{L_2}{v}$, which causes force to be exerted at a frequency of $\frac{v}{L_2}$, and causing the rope to eventually vibrate at frequency of $\frac{v}{L_2}$, which is the natural frequency of the rope at $L_2$. But I doubt the legitimacy and don't have an idea to describe it mathematically, especially how $y(x, t)$ would look like, since the flat area ruins my approaches, Solution with $Asin(\frac{2n\pi}{L_2}x-\omega t)$ is the obvious solution and the one I hope to work into.

Comment: The section of the page just said that "a pulse wave is sinuoid wave of all kinds of frequency stacked together, but which frequency doesn't produce standing wave dissipates very fast,  what's left is what we hear". What I'm interested is kind of normal mode-ish, since any wave with period(on position) associated to natural frequency can be sinuoid stacked with different amplitude, but from a "how does it become that over time" perspective. Especially with the Bocchi slide/rubber band example, where frequency from last moment clearly have nothing to do with the current string length/nat freq.

Comment: Rubber band example is to show that if it's something like resonance for string A to resonant with B they should have their least common multiple of freq in some reasonable range, but for whatever freq on the same string simply change its length whatever the previous freq is doesn't matter.

Comment: The thing that got me into thinking about forced oscillation is that if I have a pulse on freely moving/fixed two ends of a rope it would simply bounce back and forth without anything to do with natural frequency. And "energy on other freqs turning into energy with nat freq" got me thinking that nat freq is some sort of "bottom of valley" of freqs to go. Keywords such as forces and bottom of valley reminds me of Lagrangian and I would love an explanation of how it turns into something with nat freq over time, but if it comes simpler explanation would be just fine.

Comment: So to sum it up I would like to know how any wave oscillating forced would become natural modes stacked up eventually over time, from a function/functional over time perspective.

Comment: So energy loss of unsupported freq comes from the ends of the string. But what about holding down one point and releasing it? Is that from something like at one tension the rate of compositions bouncing off both ends is proportional of length^-1 and causing forces exerted on both ends having the new freq which relates to the new length hence the new natural frequency?

Comment: https://physics.nyu.edu/~physlab/GenPhysII_PhysIII/Intermediate_Physics_I_writeups/Oscillations-of-a-string-Physics-Majors-08-10-2017.pdf page 2 assume L as a function of time(not necessarily continuous), how do I do the math? Not really sure how dirichlet boundary works here, but presumably it should provide solutions nat freqs at every moment? But what about those L(t) is not continuous, like t<1 L(t)=3, t>=1 L(t)=5, how should the boundary condition now relate to nat freqs? The part that showed up in that instant is flat, how would the solution look like?

Comment: The only $L$ I see in you linked file is the length of the string. I believe this conversation is not leading somewhere as I seem to be unable to understand what you question is. I suggest you either try to divide your question down to shorter, more concrete and focused questions that will act as steps towards the final result or ask it in a different way (maybe rephrase it?).

Comment: I'll rewrite the question

Comment: done rewriting.